# document.ready is not reachable

Tags: jquery

I have problem in following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "button" value = "test" />
<script>
function firstload() {
    alert("start");
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("foo");
    });
    alert("end");
}
addEventListener('load', function () {
    'use strict';
    setTimeout(firstload, 0);
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As I did some workarround, I didn't find what is wrong with the code.

The above code is saved as php, but even not worinking when saved as html.

**I never reach the alert("end") statement, and also never reach alert("foo") statement.**

How can I write some code with $(docuemnt).ready.

Comment: you need to place the `$(document).ready` function outside the `firstload()` function. If you want to wait for all elements to load, you can use a `$(window).load()` function instead.

Comment: Why are you using the additional event listener and not just  $(document).ready ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I have never used an 'addEventListener', especially when doing an onready function.

The best practice, for jquery, is to use something like this:

```
$(function(){
   //insert code here
});

//insert other functions out here
```

Here is how you do it with .ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //insert code here
});

//insert other functions out here
```

I cannot tell you why your code didn't work, but I know for sure that this will.

Here is the link to the jquery website: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

have you tried?

```
function firstload() {
    alert("end");
}
$(function(){ /* or $(document).ready(){ */ /* if you prefere */
    firstload();
});
```

-EDIT-

A document ready inside a function wich is executed in window.load its a bit redundant.., also the alert 'end' is outside the document.ready

Comment: Have you tried _explaining_ why the OP's code doesn't work and why this will fix it?

Comment: I think I have another problem. The above works on localhost, but not working on the hosting site.
I have copied the the google api to my hosting site, and everything work fine.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the chrome/firefox console? like 404 error for the jquery file?